# Div - Background-image - dynamic (preferably byte array)

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am currently rendering background of a "div" using an image in assets folder

```
.div-class {
   background-image: url('~assets/....../imageName.png')
}
```

The new requirement is to render different images conditionally, pulling it from API. I already have a mechanism to pull byte array for image into the Angular app.

What would be the best way to display that image dynamically as background of a div?

Comment: ```[ngStyle]="{background: `url(${yourImage})`">```

Comment: or ```[style.background-image]="`url(${yourImage})`"```